# How to fill a new list with values from another two lists

Tags: list, python-3.x, fill

I was looking for an answer on stack, but I couldn't find the right answer.

I've two lists:

```py
keys = ['banana', 'orange']
values = [3, 5]
```

And I wanna make a new list looking such like that:

```py
newlist = ['banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'orange',
    'orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange']
```

Comment: Break down your problem into sub-problems: how to pair up `keys` and `values`, and how to repeat each string. Have you tried anything yourself yet?

Comment: Yes, I tried to many times, but It didn't work, I used 2 for loops

Comment: @MartijnPieters Maybe it's easy for you and you can help me

Comment: @George It's very easy using two for loops, but not very Pythonic. Post the code if you want help with it.

Comment: Please edit you question and show us the code you have so far.

Comment: Just solved my problem, answer from @svens helped a lot. 
Thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to iterate over `(value, key)` pairs.

```
out = []
for e in zip(values, keys):
    out.extend(e[0] * [e[1]])
```

It's also possible without a for loop, using a [nested list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#nested-list-comprehension):

```
[y for x in zip(values, keys) for y in x[0] * [x[1]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a lambda to multiply these values between them easily. Your lambda would take two arguments, one from each array and return the multiplication:

```
newlist = list(map(lambda x, y: [x] * y, keys, values))
```

We need to enclose the value (`x`) from `values` given to the `lambda` in square brackets in order to not get string multiplication and rather .

This results in:

```
[['banana', 'banana', 'banana'],
 ['orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange']]
```